# Binary Tree; Print in increasing order of frequency; C language

Tags: c, binary-tree

**I'm supposed to use what I know, this is a assignment for class and I'm only up to chapter 7 in the K&R book**

what I am trying to do is traverse a already created binary tree (put in lexicographical order) and print the structures in increasing order of their frequency here is my recursive treeprint. my idea to traversing the treeprint recursively is to check the pcount against the treenode count, if they are the same print the node, set its count to -4 so its out of the printing (numcount is out of use right now) so when it gets to either a null pointer or that the p->count equals -4, that should mean the tree has been fully traversed and that we should start over again and increment pcount to check for that frequency. I know something is wrong but I can't figure it out. I'm using a text file called gettysburg, I've included the text as is at the end

```
 /* treeprint: in-order print of tree p */
  void treeprint(struct tnode *p)
  {

      if(p != NULL) {
          treeprint(p->left);
          if(p->count == -4 || p == NULL){
              pcount++;
              treeprint(pt);
          }
          if(pcount == p->count) {
          printf("%4d %s\n", p->count, p->word);
          p->count = -4;
          numcount++;
      //  treeprint(p->right);
          }
          treeprint(p->right);
      }
  }
```

here is the declarations and main body:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "getch.h"
  #define MAXWORD 100

  int numcount = 1;
  int pcount = 1;
  struct tnode * pt;

  typedef struct tnode{
      char *word;
      int count;
      struct tnode *left;
      struct tnode *right;
  }treenode;


  int getword(char *, int);
  struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
  void treeprint(struct tnode *);
  int getch(void);
  void ungetch(int);
  main()
  {
      struct tnode *root;
      struct tnode *sortedtree;
      char word[MAXWORD];

      root = NULL;
      while(getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)
          if(isalpha(word[0])){
              root = addtree(root, word);
              pt = root;
          }
  //  sortedtree = treesort(sortedtree, root);
      treeprint(root);
  //  printf("so far so good \n\n");
  //  treeprint(sortedtree);
      printf("numcount = %d\n", numcount);
      return 0;
  }
```

my addtree function which builds the tree:

```
  /* addtree: add a node with w, at or below p*/
  struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w)
  {
      int cond;

      if(p == NULL) {
          p = (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
          p->word = strdup(w);
          p->count = 1;
          p->left = p->right = NULL;
      } else if ((cond = strcmp(w, p->word)) == 0)
          p->count++;
      else if (p->count < 0)
          p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
      else
          p->right = addtree(p->right, w);
      return p;
  }
```

gettysburg text:

> Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this
>   continents a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the
>   proposition that all men are created equal.  Now we are engaged in a
>   great civil war, testing whether that nation or any nation so
>   conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great
>   battle field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that
>   field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives
>   that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that
>   we should do this.  But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate we can
>   not consecrate  we can not hallow this ground. The brave men, living
>   and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor
>   power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember
>   what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is
>   for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work
>   which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced.  It is
>   rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before
>   us that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that
>   cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion that we
>   here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain that
>   this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom and that
>   government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not
>   perish from the earth.

Comment: Please remove the line number! So other people can debug/ use your code faster. Thanks

Comment: Your condition `else if (p->count < 0) p->left = addtree(p->left, w);` in `addtree()` is surprising; I think you should be using `else if (cond < 0)` instead. Also, I think the Gettysburg address uses "this continent" (singular) rather than "this continents" (plural). Having built the tree using word matching, you either need to convert it to an array to sort it or you need to build another tree by scanning the first and inserting the nodes according to frequency instead of alphabetic order of words. Be aware that you'll handle duplicate entries differently in the two tree building functions.

Comment: In `addtree()` the line `else if (p->count < 0)` should probably be `else if (cond < 0)`

Answer (score 0):

part of what's wrong is that you don't mention your approach for ordering them into frequency order.

It would be a lot easier to write a heap structure, traverse the words tree and insert each word:count into the heap, then remove and print the values from the heap.

A heap is a partially ordered tree with the largest value always at the root.  On insert and delete the tree is rebalanced to maintain this property.  There is a really efficient implementation that maps the heap into an array, s.t. root is at offset 1, the left child is at offset 2*root and right child at 2*root + 1.  A heap is a fun structure to write.

Comment: I'm only supposed to use what I know. I don't think heaps are allowed.